# Set cert permission on Server 2019 in certificate store - with DSC configuration

Tags: powershell

The following script works interactively but fails when using DSC.  DSC is a way of setting up a deployment pipeline for windows servers.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/getting-started/wingettingstarted?view=dsc-1.1

The certificate is already added to the certificate store.  This succeeds interactively with administrator authority.  It fails when in a DSC pull configuration.

```
$userName = "domain\user"
#example testuser1
$permission = "read"
#example read 
$certStoreLocation = "\LocalMachine\My"
#example \LocalMachine\My
$certThumbprint = "24235c388df63e20dea2b21e0deadbeefe21c3cd"
#example 24235c388df63e20dea2b21e0deadbeefe21c3cd

# check if certificate is already installed
$certificateInstalled = Get-ChildItem cert:$certStoreLocation | Where thumbprint -eq $certThumbprint

Write-Host $certificateInstalled



# download & install only if certificate is not already installed on machine
if ($certificateInstalled -eq $null)
{
    $message="Certificate with thumbprint:"+$certThumbprint+" does not exist at "+$certStoreLocation
    Write-Host $message -ForegroundColor Red
    exit 1;
}else
{
    try
    {
        $rule = new-object security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule $userName, $permission, allow
        $root = "c:\programdata\microsoft\crypto\rsa\machinekeys"
        $l = ls Cert:$certStoreLocation
        $l = $l |? {$_.thumbprint -like $certThumbprint}
        $l |%{
            $keyname = $_.privatekey.cspkeycontainerinfo.uniquekeycontainername
            Write-Host "Keyname:  $keyname"
            Write-Host $keyname
            $p = [io.path]::combine($root, $keyname)
            if ([io.file]::exists($p))
            {
                $acl = get-acl -path $p
                $acl.addaccessrule($rule)
                echo $p
                set-acl $p $acl
                Write-Host "Set ACL"
            }
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        Write-Host "Caught an exception:" -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Host "$($_.Exception)" -ForegroundColor Red
        exit 1;
    }    
}

exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

error message:

```
VERBOSE: [HOSTNAME]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]  [[Script]SSLcertificateRights]  in 0.1560 seconds.
PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_ScriptResource  failed to execute Set-TargetResource functionality with error message:
PowerShell Desired State Configuration does not support execution of commands in an interactive mode. Please ensure
that the underlying command is not prompting for user input, such as missing mandatory parameter, confirmation prompt
etc.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderOperationExecutionFailure
    + PSComputerName        : hostname.domain.ext
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My boss refactored it and made it work with DSC

```
[securestring]$secStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Node.CertificatePassword -AsPlainText -Force

        [pscredential]$certCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Node.CertificateUser, $secStringPassword)



        PfxImport SSLcertificate

        {

            Ensure     = 'Present'

            Thumbprint = $Node.CertificateThumbPrint

            Path       = $Node.CertificatePath

            Location   = 'LocalMachine'

            Exportable = $true

            Store      = 'My'

            FriendlyName = $Node.CertificateFriendlyName

            Credential = $certCred

        }



        script SSLcertificateRights

        {

            #always replace

            TestScript = {

                    return $false

             }

            GetScript = { return "patate" }

            SetScript = {

                $rule = new-object security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule $Using:Node.CertificateAdminUser, read, allow

                $root = "c:\programdata\microsoft\crypto\rsa\machinekeys"

                $l = ls Cert:"\LocalMachine\My"

                $l = $l |? {$_.thumbprint -like $Using:Node.CertificateThumbPrint}

                $l |% {

                    $keyname = $_.privatekey.cspkeycontainerinfo.uniquekeycontainername

                    $p = [io.path]::combine($root, $keyname)

                    if ([io.file]::exists($p))

                    {

                        $acl = get-acl -path $p

                        $acl.addaccessrule($rule)

                        echo $p

                        set-acl $p $acl

                    }

                }

            }

            DependsOn = '[PfxImport]SSLcertificate'

        }
```